# How can I put a column of Button in an ASP GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, datacolumn

I'm pretty new to ASP.Net, and I've hit a bit of a wall.  I'm binding my GridView to a TableAdapter -- that part is working fine -- and I want to add a column that contains buttons, all of them with the same text.

Here's a fragment of my aspx that creates the GridView:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="LSResultsGrid" runat="server" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="5">
   </asp:GridView>
```

And here's what I'm trying to do in my C# code:

```
    LSResultsAdapter = new LSResultsTableAdapter();
    LSResultsAdapter.CreateQualificationSamples(QualID, 0);

    LSResultsGrid.DataSource = LSResultsAdapter.GetLSSampleData(1);

    Button b = new Button();
    b.Text = "Show";

    DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Reps", typeof(Button));
    col.DefaultValue = b;

    var lsResultsTable = ((QCServer.HVIMillData.LSResultsDataTable)LSResultsGrid.DataSource);
    lsResultsTable.Columns.Add(col);

    LSResultsGrid.DataBind();
```

If I remove the "typeof(Button)" parameter from the DataColumn constructor,  then my table shows with the new column -- but the text on the buttons is "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button"; if I leave the parameter as shown here, the column just doesn't appear at all (there is no exception thrown).

Thanks, anyone who can lend a hand.

Comment: there are plenty of examples on the internet as well as MSDN in regards to how to use GridView Templates `ItemTemplate` is what you want to search on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb498195.aspx

Comment: I'll give that a look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to add a button in gridview. Your method will  work, just change `col.DefaultValue = b;` to `col.DefaultValue = b.Text;` but this is a difficult method for a beginner.

A couple of easier methods can be accomplished in the markup itself: inside gridview you can add:
type 1:

```
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Show" />
</Columns>
```

type 2:

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate> My Action
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="showbtn" runat="server" text="Show"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Reps")%>' OnClick="showbtn_Click" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

with the second type of button, build a method to match `OnClick="showbtn_Click"` that will perform your desired action when the button is clicked. Same with the first method.

Here is a third type, if you really must do it from the codebehind, add the button field to your grid, not the datatable:

```
    ButtonField col = new ButtonField();
    col.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
    col.DataTextField = ("Reps"); //or whatever bound column you want to show.
    LSResultsGrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  

I'd really rather do it in C#; everyone in our group are very experienced w/ C#, and I'm the only one who can even spell ASP.   I tried the C# change you suggested; it won't work, because if I create the DataColumn with typeof(Button), it won't let me assign a string to the DefaultValue.  If I omit the parameter, or set the param to typeof(string), the column doesn't display at all.

Your ItemTemplate example looks like it will be very helpful, though.  I'll give that a shot.

Comment: The first aspx suggestion above did the trick.  Thanks!

Still, for my own edification; if anyone knows how to fix the C# code, I'd be interested in learning.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a C# approach. `datatable.columns.add()` method insists on strings. I'm sure there's a way a genius out there has figured out a way to override it and fill it with a Button, the three approaches above work well. You can place those buttons anywhere, during any event: OnLoad, OnPostBack, OnDataBound, etc., and not necessarily inside the GridView.